# Simpy Resource with no waiting queue

Tags: simulation, simpy

I want a resource to be able to handle 100 processes at a time (parallely). As far as i know i can do this by setting capacity to 100. But I also want this resource not to have any waiting queue. For example lets say resource is in full capacity and 101th process requested to use the resource. When it sees there is no free slot, that process should just terminate.

Is there any pythonic - SimPyic way i can achieve this?